# The use of Generic parameter raises error

Tags: java, arrays, generics

```
public static<T> int getUsedSlotsSize(T[] arr) 
{
    int index = 0;
    while(arr[index] != null)
        index++;
    return index + 1;
}

int a = getUsedSlotsSize(arr);
```

eclipse tells me to change the method parameter **arr** to *byte[]*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I presume you have a `byte[]` rather than a `Byte[]`.

Comment: Generic types can't represent primitive types so `<T>` can't represent `byte`, but it can represent Byte which is a reference type (here a class).

Comment: A primitive type can't be `null`. So `arr[index] != null` wouldn't work for a `byte` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not show which type is used for `arr` within `getUsedSlotsSize(arr)`.
If you are using

```
byte[] arr = new byte(anySize);
int a = getUsedSlotsSize(arr);
```

then you have to change the type of your array into `Byte[]` as mentioned in the comments.

```
Byte[] arr = new Byte(anySize);
int a = getUsedSlotsSize(arr);
```